# The content in my sidebar no longer shrinks along with the browser window when I set it to display: grid

Tags: html, css, media-queries, css-grid

Before I declared `display: grid` on my `<aside>` sidebar (inside the `@media (min-width: 600px)` query), the content would still shrink as I dragged the sides of my browser window to make it smaller.

But once I declare `display: grid`, it no longer shrinks.

Are there additional properties that I need to set? And for which attributes?

Here is a [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/10ig9kv) of the problem I am trying to share.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: century gothic;
}

#contact-page {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 25px;
}

#side-bar {
  background: #CFA5D7;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #FFE3EF;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFE3EF;
}

#moeru {
  max-width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #FFE3EF;
}

#message-form {
  padding: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 15px;
}

.form-group {
  display: grid;
}

.form-group input,
#submit {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}

.form-group label {
  width: 100%;
  align-self: end;
}

.form-whole-width {
  grid-column: 1/3
}

#message {
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

label {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  #contact-page {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 30% 1fr;
    grid-gap: 25px;
  }
  #side-bar {
    background: #CFA5D7;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #FFE3EF;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
  ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFE3EF;
  }
  #moeru {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #FFE3EF;
  }
  #message-form {
    padding: 20px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 15px;
  }
  .form-group {
    display: grid;
  }
  .form-group input,
  #submit {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
  }
  .form-group label {
    width: 100%;
    align-self: end;
  }
  .form-whole-width {
    grid-column: 1/3
  }
  #message {
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
  }
  label {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Contact Form with Grid</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="contact.css">
</head>

<body>
  <main id="contact-page">
    <aside id="side-bar">
      <img src="https://scontent.fmnl9-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/117642520_2687382111527878_668441420531344703_n.png?_nc_cat=104&ccb=1-3&_nc_sid=09cbfe&_nc_eui2=AeGeIeqT_nRIcbj9bsBkEmOokF65t-hNn8CQXrm36E2fwDd8FpSrtY1kN-tyqglYXMSeh5Y_-hSoM7i3CoW-l9iq&_nc_ohc=AWVq1gO2ATYAX-3W0KM&_nc_ht=scontent.fmnl9-1.fna&oh=0c19981f3ddef215e4a72806a6a1e8dc&oe=606EE8EE"
        id="moeru" alt="Logo">
      <div>
        <h2>
          <center>Company Name</center>
        </h2>
        <ul id="contact-info">
          <li><a href="#">Facebook Page</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">_ on Tumblr</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Call or text: #####</a></li>
          <li><a href="#@gmail.com">#@gmail.com</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </aside>

    <form id="message-form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="skype">Skype</label>
        <input type="text" name="skype" id="skype">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email Address</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="subject">Subject</label>
        <input type="text" name="Subject" id="subject">
      </div>
      <div class="form-whole-width">
        <label for="message">Write your message</label>
        <textarea id="message"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-whole-width">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
      </div>
    </form>
  </main>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have set the extra space to **30%** in `grid-template-columns: 30% 1fr`. What result do you want to get? Should the layout be immutable?

Comment: the 30% is for the sidebar, while 1fr for the input fields when the window is maximized. I want to achieve prntscr.com/10ii5iv where the content inside the sidebar auto adjusts. This screenshot is taken before I set the sidebar to display:grid. Weirdly enough, the auto-adjusting behavior disappears when display: grid is declared for the sidebar as seen here: prntscr.com/10ig9kv

Answer (score 1):

Can anyone verify if my solution is okay?

I have instead set a `min-width` for the containers where content would overflow when the window size is lowered like in the [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/10ig9kv).

By setting `min-width` on the containers, the content would not overflow because the containers would no longer be small enough.

**Initially I wanted to be able to shrink the window as much as I want, with all the content adjusting to it** (it is how it works before I declared `display: grid` on the sidebar), but I cannot find a different way to prevent the overflow that occurs when `display: grid` is declared.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: century gothic;
}

#contact-page {
  width: 80%;
  min-width: 450px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 25px;
}

#side-bar {
  background: #CFA5D7;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #FFE3EF;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFE3EF;
}

#moeru {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 150px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #FFE3EF;
}

#message-form {
  padding: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 15px;
}

.form-group {
  display: grid;
}

.form-group input,
#submit {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}

.form-group label {
  width: 100%;
  align-self: end;
}

#message {
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

label {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
  #contact-page {
    width: 80%;
    min-width: 1040px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 30% 1fr;
    grid-gap: 25px;
  }
  #side-bar {
    background: #CFA5D7;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #FFE3EF;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
  ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFE3EF;
  }
  #moeru {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #FFE3EF;
  }
  #message-form {
    padding: 20px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 15px;
  }
  .form-group {
    display: grid;
  }
  .form-group input,
  #submit {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
  }
  .form-group label {
    width: 100%;
    align-self: end;
  }
  .form-whole-width {
    grid-column: 1/3
  }
  #message {
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
  }
  label {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Contact Form with Grid</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="contact.css">
</head>

<body>
  <main id="contact-page">
    <aside id="side-bar">
      <img src="https://scontent.fmnl9-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/117642520_2687382111527878_668441420531344703_n.png?_nc_cat=104&ccb=1-3&_nc_sid=09cbfe&_nc_eui2=AeGeIeqT_nRIcbj9bsBkEmOokF65t-hNn8CQXrm36E2fwDd8FpSrtY1kN-tyqglYXMSeh5Y_-hSoM7i3CoW-l9iq&_nc_ohc=AWVq1gO2ATYAX-3W0KM&_nc_ht=scontent.fmnl9-1.fna&oh=0c19981f3ddef215e4a72806a6a1e8dc&oe=606EE8EE"
        id="moeru" alt="Logo">
      <div>
        <h2>
          <center>Company Name</center>
        </h2>
        <ul id="contact-info">
          <li><a href="#">Facebook Page</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">_ on Tumblr</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Call or text: #####</a></li>
          <li><a href="#@gmail.com">#@gmail.com</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </aside>

    <form id="message-form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="skype">Skype</label>
        <input type="text" name="skype" id="skype">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email Address</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="subject">Subject</label>
        <input type="text" name="Subject" id="subject">
      </div>
      <div class="form-whole-width">
        <label for="message">Write your message</label>
        <textarea id="message"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-whole-width">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
      </div>
    </form>
  </main>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is designed as a FAQ database of easy to understand "question->answer" pairs. You are asking another question in an answer but nobody will look for your new question asked in an answer. Experts who are willing to help usually filter out answered questions so your question drops out of theirs search because it is already answered. [Use this button when you want to ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) but be sure you already looked for the answer already. Alternatively you can update your original question post with extra details to keep your question open